# Not able to read email from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-ios-sdk

I'm trying to read user info from `Parse`
I can read both `name` and `phone` (among lots else) fine, but the `email` column is not being red.

I set the user info like this:

```
        PFUser.current()?["name"] = name
        PFUser.current()?["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber
        PFUser.current()?["email"] = emailAddress
```

And trying to read like this:

```
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
    if let users = objects {
       for object in users {
         if let user = object as? PFUser {   
             if let getName = user["name"] as? String {
                 var name = String()
                 name = getName
                 self.informationLabels[18].text = name
                 }

                 if let getPhone = user["phoneNumber"] as? String {
                 var phone = String()
                 phone = getPhone
                 self.informationLabels[19].text = phone
                 }

                  if let getMail = user["email"] as? String {
                  var mail = String()
                  mail = getMail
                  self.informationLabels[20].text = mail
                   }
```

Comment: Maybe  email field got removed from PFUser with explicit reasons.

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. Can you see that email addresses are being saved in your Parse Dashboard?

Answer (score -1):

Accessing user's email requires the masterkey as a security mesure.

Comment: The `masterKey` is not required given that the permissions are set up correctly.